# Compilation error when perfoming SSE in C++

Tags: x86, sse, simd

My code is very simple for understanding SSE. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
using namespace std;
struct cVector  {
float x,y,z; };
int main()
{
cVector vec1;
vec1.x=0.5;
vec1.y=1.5;
vec1.z=-3.141;
__asm 
{
movups xmm1, vec1
mulps xmm1, xmm1
movups vec1, xmm1
}
cout << vec1.x << " " << vec1.y << " " << vec1.z << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. for compilation i used the following command:

```
$ gcc -o program -msse -mmmx -msse2 sse.cpp
```

The following error I found:

```
sse.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sse.cpp:20: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
sse.cpp:21: error: ‘movups’ was not declared in this scope
sse.cpp:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘xmm1’
```

Can anyone please help me how can I remove this error?

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do this with inline asm - use the provided intrinsics, e.g.

```
// ...

#include <xmmintrin.h>

// ...

int main()
{
    cVector vec1;

    vec1.x = 0.5f;
    vec1.y = 1.5f;
    vec1.z = -3.141f;

    __m128 v = _mm_loadu_ps(&vec1.x); // load unaligned floats to SSE vector
    v = _mm_mul_ps(v, v);             // square
    _mm_storeu_ps(&vec1.x, v);        // store SSE vector back to unaligned floats

    cout << vec1.x << " " << vec1.y << " " << vec1.z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```